# Import (download) webpage/image sequence to computer

Tags: r, loops, rvest

I want to save images in `pdf` or `jpeg` format to my computer from multiple links using `R`. I tried stacking the links and using a loop to do this, but it didn't work. I tried to use the `download.file` function, but it gives the following error:

```
Error in download.file(image, "images", mode = "wb") : invalid 'url' argument.
```

Please what can I do to fix my code or is there another function more effective than `download.file`?

```
library (rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "https://acervo.folha.com.br/busca.do?sort=desc&page=1&decadeStatus=&keyword=exato%3Ad%C3%ADvida+p%C3%BAblica&periododesc=01%2F04%2F2021+-+30%2F04%2F2021&por=Por+Per%C3%ADodo&startDate=01%2F04%2F2021&endDate=30%2F04%2F2021&days=&month=&year=&jornais=1"

pagina <- read_html(url)
nodes_imagens <- html_nodes(pagina, xpath =  "//div/a/figure/img")

jpeg <- html_attr(nodes_imagens, name = "src")

x <- 1:20
tabela_imagens <- tibble(x,jpeg)

for (link in tabela_imagens$jpeg) {
  print(link)
  imagem <- read_html(link)
  download.file(imagem,"imagens", mode = 'wb')}
```

Comment: Hello! I want to save images in pdf or jpeg format to my computer from multiple links using R. I tried stacking the links and using a loop to do this, but it didn't work. I tried to use the download.fille function, but it gives the following error:Error in download.file(image, "images", mode = "wb") : invalid 'url' argument.

Please what can I do to fix my code or is there another function more effective than download.fille?

Comment: Check, if `imagem` contains a correct urlfor each iteration of your `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, it does. The error appears as soon as I include the last line of code with the download.fille function

Answer (score 0):

To download the images we can use `download.file` and `basename`,

```
 for(i in jpeg){
  print(i)
  download.file(i, basename(i), mode = 'wb')
}
```